# Odd, new 500 error on getimagesize, fread after nameserver change

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, cpanel, nameservers

We've been working for the past few months on a website that worked excellently when you simply went to the dev server's IP address. The now-former website was still running on the domain. *When we pointed the domain's nameservers (yesterday afternoon) to the new server*, the website IS loading as expected, but is experiencing a 500 error on a call to PHP's getimagesize **for non-relative urls only**...

So in this example, the first works as expected, the second fails on a 500 error.

```
echo print_r( getimagesize( "images/bluescentric-logo-marujo.png" ), true );
echo print_r( getimagesize( "https://www.mywebsite.com/images/categories/hats/Hats-category-Image.png" );
```

I used two different image paths for reference, but if we use the full url vs. relative path for the *same* image, we get the same result. Obviously, it appears there's a config issue with the file directory, but I've tried everything I can imagine:

1) **ALL files in question do exist and can be viewed in a browser.** The getimagesize is failing indiscriminately on all. This includes images that DO load in the page's html, with the src being the full URL. In other words, http is loading the images without problem with an identical URL that is failing in getimagesize.

2) We checked the error log in cPanel it said absolutely nothing referencing this issue or any of the images or files that we're having trouble with.

3) It's also experiencing the same behavior on fread, which lead us to believe nothing on our domain could find files (with a url that pointed to the domain).

4) **php.ini file is default**

5) In htaccess, we tried removing rules and ultimately tried it with an almost blank htaccess (we left this rule, FWIW: SetEnv DOC_ROOT /home/mywebsite/public_html/) and the problem persists. FYI there are NO rules that apply to the image folder or anything that we could determine would rewrite an image file's path, but again, we tried with basically no rules and had the same problem.

6) The permissions for some of the image files was 644, so we changed it to 755  with no change.

Look, I suppose it could reasonably be that it hasn't fully propagated yet and that is causing problems, but it will have been 24 hours pretty soon and this behavior has not changed since it , and with the unusual server-side nature of the issues, we had believed (9 long hours ago and counting) that it was an errant config issue.

So please forgive my asking a complicated technical issue that could conceivably be simply propagation, but based on what we saw, we decided that it was better to look for an error on our end rather than "wait it out" and hope for a recurring behavior to just change.

We're just completely out of ideas. And coffee.

Comment: Out of all that I don't see any reference to your web server error log and what it's saying is the cause of the 500 error. That's the first place that should be looked at.

Comment: The cPanel error log was the first place we checked and I didn't say anything because it said absolutely nothing. It's throwing a number of "unable to find image" errors from Google and other referrers because we just changed the website over, but there is nothing referencing this issue or any of the images or files that we're having trouble with.

Comment: That's a huge reason why I don't use control panels. They bog down the sever and change the location for everything. I worked for 2 hosting companies so I know. Anyway, There are usually domain specific error logs instead of the main one for cpanel/apache. Make sure you're looking in here `/usr/local/apache/domlogs/`